# android studio 3.0 no suggestions in XML with custom elements

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have updated Android Studio to 3.0  and now I don't have suggestions in XML for custom elements. Sometimes it works, but mostly not.

I made "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart", but the same
Removed all Android Studio folders and temporary files (`"*.idea", "*.iml", ".gradle", "build"... logs..`) in the system, but still the same.
Researched in configurations, but haven't found any related to this.

Tried again on previous Android Studio (2.3.3), there works.

XML File sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".view.activity.WelcomePageActivity">

    <com.innovattic.font.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does someone know where or how to configure this to highlight? Or is it a bug of 3.0 version?

on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

1)Delete `.idea folder` and all `.iml files` from the project
2)Restart Android Studio
3) Finally rebuild the gradle.

Comment: Tried. "Removed all Android Studio folders and temporary files in the system" is exactly about this.